# Performance Tuning in Apache webserver - Maxclient value

Tags: performance, apache, httpserver, ibmhttpserver

Have 2 Apache IBM HTTP servers with the following settings

ThreadLimit          150

ServerLimit          8

MaxClients           1200

ThreadsPerChild      150

The server has 8 core and 24 Gig Ram (Linux box) I'm looking at increasing the maxclient values. What all  are the things I should be considering ?

Also when I do ss -s

Transport Total     IP        IPv6

- 1243      -         -

RAW       0         0         0

UDP       20        15        5

TCP       836       803       33

INET      856       818       38

FRAG      0         0         0

Does the TCP Total value (836) correspond to the Maxclients setting.?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no real correspondence. MaxClients is the maximum number of concurrent threads Apache will use. If Apache only ever handled static files, the share of open sockets on Apache's port would be roughly capped by MaxClients.

But backend connections and connection pooling mean you could have far more open sockets than threads (maxclients).

1200 is pretty modest, 2000-3000 is still reasonable.

You can chart the usage via mod_mpmstats.